# Command the draw a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, drawing

Let $G$  be a simple undirected graph. Let the set of vertices be $V=\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\rbrace $, and let the edges set be $E=\lbrace (a, b): a\text{ divides }b\text{ or }b\text{ divides }a;\text{ and }a\neq b~\forall a, b\in V\rbrace $.

How to draw the graph of this type?

Comment: A very similar question is answered in the documentation for [`RelationGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html). Here's one way to do it: ```RelationGraph[
 Unequal[#1, #2] && (Divisible[#1, #2] || Divisible[#2, #1]) &, 
 Range[10], VertexLabels -> "Name"]``` - note if you use `CoprimeQ` instead of both `Divisible`s then 1 is not handled quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
a = Tuples[Range[10], {2}];
edges = Select[a, (Mod[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 0 && #[[1]] =!= #[[2]]) &]
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]